# How to quickly convert a date into seconds for comparison in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I am writing a method to return how many seconds old a user is. I'm having a lot of issues with an error that I don't understand. It's as follows:

> (eval):1: (eval):1: uninitialized constant Date (NameError)

I've created a class `Age < Date` so that I can use all the methods in the Date module as well. The issue I keep running into is with my `in_seconds` method as follows:

```
def in_seconds
    current = Time.now
    bday = Date.new(year, month, day) # this is the birthday of the user
    age = (current - bday).to_s
    return "You are #{age} years old."
end
```

I'm considering revising the `initialize` method to include the parameters `(YYYY, MM, DD)` so that I can keep a running birthday date for each user, as follows:

```
John = Age.new(1985, 04, 27) 
# sets @age to 910,993,128 seconds

Angela = Age.new(1991, 03, 15)
# sets @age to 725,405,928 seconds
```

My biggest issue is that I can't seem to get rid of that error up there. Ruby keeps throwing back the fact that there's an uninitialized constant. What constant? After a few hours of research, I've drawn a complete blank. How can I remedy that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can subtract a Date from a Time. I'd suggest using `Time.new` to get your `bday` variable. That will also get rid of your error - @MarkThomas is right about the need to require that library.

It's not clear why Age needs to be a subclass of Date (or of Time, for that matter) to do what you want to do. If you add this method to any object, it will calculate the Time in seconds between a date and now:

```
def in_seconds(year, month, day)
  back_then = Time.new(year, month, day)
  seconds_since_then = Time.now - back_then
end
```

Comment: I'm really attempting to just get two dates represented as the number of seconds since the epoch. The first date is the user's birthday, and the second is the current time. They're both integers, so I don't see why it should be so difficult. Any thoughts on getting around the `Date` and `Time` compatibility issues all together?

Comment: Time is stored internally as the number of seconds since the epoch. I don't understand why the Date library is needed here. If your method defines `current` as `Time.now` and `bday` as `Time.new(year, month date)`, `current - bday` is going to be your age in seconds, simple as that. I'll put an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to get rid of the issues thanks to Steve Rowley's suggestion that I can't compare a Date object to a Time object. I decided to only use Time objects to get ages converted to integers as follows:

```
require 'time'

class Age 

    def initialize(year, month, day)
    # the parameters are assumed to be integers
        @age = Time.parse("#{year}-#{month}-#{day}").to_i
    end

    def in_sec
        return Time.now.to_i - @age
    end

end
```

So far, I'm not having any issues. It seems like the biggest problem was coming from using the `Date` module at all.

Answer (score 0):

umm

```
date.to_time.to_i
```

converts it into seconds after Jan 1 1970